# Occasional RenderScript load failure - Loading of ScriptC script failed

Tags: renderscript, android-renderscript

I have a renderscript which works fine in all of my test runs. However, a very few users (across Android N,O and P) are running into load failure. I'm not using support library version as minSDKVersion is 21. Are there any RS logs that i can collect?

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28

    renderscriptTargetApi 21
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false

Caused by android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed. at android.renderscript.ScriptC.(ScriptC.java:82)
```

Comment: could you find out a solution??

Comment: No, fallback to CPU